# Transformer leakage reactance

Tags: transformer, electric-machine

For a 4:1 transformer,the leakage reactance referred to secondary side is 0.05 pu. Then what will be the leakage reactance referred to primary? and how?

Comment: Ask yourself what the term "pu" means.

Answer (score 1):

I think that question is incomplete. both winding primary and secondary have some leakage reatance and resistance. when they are refereed to one side then the other side reactance is multiplied by sq of turn ratio and added to existing. As you are using per-unit notation and there is no clarification in question hence it is hard to understand exactly.
In general if number of turns in primary =$$n1$$
number of turns in secondary winding=$$n2$$
then primary leakagee reffered to secondary side is : $$z1 * sq(n2/n1)$$
and total secondary reffered reactance is: $$z2+ z1 * sq(n2/n1)$$